# Dúvida com redirecionamento em php a partir de uma caixa de dialogo

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Tenho o seguinte arquivo php chamado de remove.php, com ele eu estou removendo um registro de uma tabela, depois de removido exibo uma caixa de dialogo retornando se pode ser removido ou não, gostaria que ao clicar om OK nessa caixa de dialogo eu pudesse me direcionar a outro arquivo php.

Temtei usar o `header("Location: lista.php")`, porém quando uso no arquivo aa caixa de dialógo nem apareçe pra mim na tela e já sou redirecionado ao outro arquivo, também tentei usar o `header("refresh: 5; url=lista.php")`, mas também não obtive sucesso.

Alguém mais experiente poderia me ajudar?

```
<?php   
    include("cabecalho.php");
    include("conecta.php");

    function removeProduto($conexao, $id){
        $query = "delete from colaboradores where cpf = '{$id}'";
        return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
    }

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    removeProduto($conexao, $id);
    $ret = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);

    if($ret == 1){
?>

<script>
    confirm('colaborador excluído com sucesso!');
</script>

<?php   
    }else if($ret == -1){
?>

<script>
    confirm('colaborador não pode ser excluído!');
</script>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso deve ser feito pelo JS não pelo PHP

Você pode fazer:

```
if($ret == 1){
?>
        <script>
        confirm('colaborador excluído com sucesso!');
        window.location = 'https://example.com/lista.php';
        </script>
<?php       
}else if($ret == -1){
?>    
        <script>
        confirm('colaborador não pode ser excluído!');
        window.location = 'https://example.com/lista.php';
        </script>
<?php    
}
?>
```

Ou mais simples:

```
?>    
        <script>
        confirm('colaborador <?php echo $ret == 1 ? "excluído com sucesso!" : "não pode ser excluído!" ?>');
        window.location = 'https://example.com/lista.php';
        </script>
<?php
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda Guilherme. ;)